# Can a cron job be set to run every hour at 5 minutes after the hour?

Tags: cron

I would like to run a cron job once an hour at 5 minutes after the hour.
I have not found an example of how to do this. Is it even possible?

Comment: This is absolutely possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - you can specify the minuted value as 5, and leave the rest as wildcards:

```
5 * * * *
```

Comment: But wont that run every 5 minutes as opposed to 5 minutes after the hour?

Comment: @Tim No. Step values (like every five minutes) are accomplished by the `/` character: `*/5 * * * *`.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Danila. Most appreciated

Comment: Quick add on question.  If I wanted to have a job run at 10 minutes after ever hour and 40 minutes after every hour, would I create two cron entries?

Comment: @Tim no need. Each field of the crontab can take a comma-delimited list: `10,40 * * * *`.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again Mureinik